# jQuery not working in Internet Explorer 8 Mode of F12 Development Tools

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, ie-developer-tools

Can anyone see why jQuery isn't working in IE8 mode (from F12 developer tools) on this page:

http://www.coolpersonalisedgifts.co.uk/products_customise_withpic.asp?varid=1001.

It works fine in IE9, all recent FF, Chrome etc.  I need to get it working in IE8 because a lot of the people who visit the site are using XP with IE8.

If someone does look at it please be aware that it is a long page.

It doesn't seem that even the $(document).ready(function() is running because a simple alert placed in it doesn't come up.  I've tried some of the fixes I've found (like making sure all script tags are type="text/JavaScript") but without success.

Comment: I get a message to upgrade my browser in IE9 (IE8 browser mode).

Comment: Smamatti - this has now been removed.  It was just used as a test.

Comment: Well it ran/appeared. You wrote: `It doesn't seem that even the $(document).ready(function() is running because a simple alert placed in it doesn't come up.`

Comment: Smamatti - That wasn't the alert I alluded to.  The alert you mentioned came from and included file in the header.  kirilloid's diagnosis is correct.  I need to find a solution to that now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The very first part of inline script have `window.addEventListener`. IE8 doesn't support `addEventListener`.

Comment: Disabling that pops up a "Please upgrade your browser message" which you may like to address also.

Comment: Sorry Alex, that was something put in to test the browser - it has been removed

Comment: kirilloid - Thank you you're correct.  Can you suggest what I can use instead of it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are known issues with jQuery 1.6.2 and IE8, try using a later version of jQuery.

Comment: Thanks Lazarus - I'll certainly do that.